# Form hidden input

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So, I want to input a value inside the form which is hidden. This value will be a an id of a current user, thus the user doesnt need to input anything.

Till now I did this code in the form but still, the id is being inputted as NULL:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden("id",
[
    "options" => $currentUserr
]);
```

$currentUser is the Id of the current user in the website. How can I place that value inside the DB ?

Comment: First things first, I'd advise against doing that, without form tampering protection this would allow users to pass arbitrary values for the user id. That being said, why is the field named `id`? That's usually a name for a primary key, and when baking entities, disallowed for mass assignment.

Comment: @ndm yes you are right, but I'm actually trying to input in the DB the user Id of the person who's creating an object

Comment: I suspected that, still, same concern, same question.

Comment: The [Footprint](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint) plugin does exactly this.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yep, great alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Your input must have the `name` attribute. Once done, you can retrieve all your request parameters, even the hidden fields.

Comment: Didn't understand well this answer. I'm getting the current user Id and in the Form I'm trying to insert that user id so that the DB field 'Id' won't be null and then I can access that object with that user id

Comment: Can you print the id before send to the database ?

Comment: Thanks for the help but it's solved. I've added the Id when saving the data in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like

```
echo $this->Form->input("id",[‘type’=>’hidden’,
"options" => $currentUser]);
```

You can take notes from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

BUT - that said - you shouldnt actually use either one of those. And omit any fields that serve no real purpose for the view and its form. Instead you should inject those fields into the data array prior to saving. See http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this**

```
 //First you get hidden field value

    $current_user_id = $this->request->data("id");

//and then save that data to database table

  $this->User->save(array('id' => $current_user_id));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm trying to save the value inside a view

Comment: where is the problem brother . will you tell once again ?

Comment: Sure, the problem is that I'm filling a form to create a 'Car' in my example. When I'm filling this form the id of the user is remaining NULL, hence, later on, I can't access 'My cars' list because of the NULL field in the DB. In the code example that I provided, I've tried inserting the value id which is inside the $currentUser while filling the form that's why it is set to  'hidden'

Comment: Brother, first set your id field column in the database table as primary key and also set auto increment to it, then you can add your form data to database ,so you don't need to add id value to the DB table column because this column automatically generated unique id itself every record.

Comment: I've research another method. I'm saving the id not in the view but in the controller after before saving all objects.